# Crop images in android backwards

Tags: android, imageview, crop

After searching a lot , i post this thread as a last hope .

i placed two images one above the other and a seek bar over it , i want the upper image to get cropped in such a way that the lower image gets the visibility of the cropped space alone . And the progress is managed through the seekbar thumb .

[image] this is how my view looks like .

[image] and when i move the seekbar , the image gets cropped by rightside but i want the image to get cropped by left .

```
my class file

     skbr = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    skbr.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
        {
            Bitmap img = getcroppedimg(arg0.getProgress());
            img2.setImageBitmap(img);
            img2.getLayoutParams().width = img.getWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
        {
            Bitmap img = getcroppedimg(arg0.getProgress());
            img2.setImageBitmap(img);
            img2.getLayoutParams().width = img.getWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) 
        {
            Bitmap img = getcroppedimg(arg0.getProgress());
            img2.setImageBitmap(img);
            img2.getLayoutParams().width = img.getWidth();
        }
    });

    public Bitmap getcroppedimg(double y)
    {
        Log.e(" progress ", ""+y);
        int x = (int)Math.round(( y / 100)*600); 
        Bitmap originalImg1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.neutral_left_without);
        Bitmap originalImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.neutral_left_without);

        Bitmap cropimg ;
        if((originalImg.getWidth()-x)>0)
            cropimg = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImg, 0, 0, originalImg.getWidth()-x, originalImg.getHeight());
        else if((originalImg.getWidth()+x)<= originalImg1.getWidth())
            cropimg = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImg, 0, 0, originalImg.getWidth()+x, originalImg.getHeight());
        else
            cropimg = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImg, 0, 0, originalImg.getWidth(), originalImg.getHeight());
        return cropimg ;
    }
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong or is there any alternative to this . Any related answers are welcomed .